# In Spring framework, fetch saved entity from database to compare to modified, unsaved entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Using Java and Spring, I have an entity that is modified but has not yet been persisted. I want to compare it to its original state, the state that still exists in the database. However, when I do a fetch for the entity to get the old state, it always returns the entity in the *modified* state.

---

An example, to better illustrate the point, is shown below.

- The `MyEntity` class represents the entity.
- The `MyEntityRepository` class is a [Spring Data Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) used for performing database interactions for the `MyEntity` entity.
- The `MyService` class has a transactional method called `save` which compares the new version of MyEntity (called `entity`) with `oldEntity`. If `entity` and `oldEntity` are different, then `entity` is saved to the database; otherwise, it is not saved.

The `oldEntity` is fetched from the repository and compared against `entity`. However, when this is done, `oldEntity` is **always** the same as `entity`. (The changed values in `entity` are reflected in `oldEntity`.)

Since `entity` is not yet saved, how can I fetch the state of the entity as it currently exists in the database and not in the current context? Is it possible using Spring annotations or setting a propagation value to go outside of the current persistence context to fetch the entity so that it is the real, persisted value and not the one in the current context?

---

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowire
    private MyEntityRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public boolean save(MyEntity entity) {
        MyEntity oldEntity = repository.findOne(entity.getId());
        if (entity.compareTo(oldEntity) != 0) {
            repository.save(entity);
        } 
    }
}

public interface MyEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    MyEntity findByName(String name);
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    public Long getId() { ... }
    public void setId(Long id) { ... }
    public String getName() { ... }
    public void setName(String name) { ... }
    public int compareTo(MyEntity entity) { ... }

}
```

Comment: What is the use case for doing this?

Comment: Depending on your provider, a flush can occur when a query about to be executed depends on new or updated entities in the current persistence context. This explains then what you are seeing - your provider flushes the pending changes to ensure the consistency of the query about to be issued. O

Comment: @MarkOfHall My particular use case invokes additional processing if and only if one of several entity attributes changed. As a result, I would like to fetch the saved entity state and compare it to the modified entity state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind the behaviour of how transactions work with entities. When you do `MyEntity entity = myEntityRepository.findByName("test");` And call something like `entity.setName();` within a transaction, then once the transaction is finished the name column in the database will be updated. You will need to use the entity manager to remove an entity within a transaction before calling `setName` to stop the database from being updated. But then you will need to re-add it if you wanted to save the changes to name.